# HtmlAgilityPack - getting error when looping through nodes. Doesn't make sense

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get all nodes below but I am getting an error message of:

Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'GetAttributeValue' accepts this number of arguments.

```
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument() 
doc.LoadHtml("shaggybevo.com/board/register.php") 
Dim docNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode 
Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = docNode.SelectNodes("//input")

For Each node As HtmlNode In nodes
    Dim id As String = node.GetAttributeValue("id")
Next
```

Any ideas on why I am getting this error message? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a default value as a second parameter to [GetAttributeValue](http://www.kbs.uni-hannover.de/~minack/beagle++/beagle-0.0.13.2-doxygen/d5/d8d/classHtmlAgilityPack_1_1HtmlNode.html#238e3147aa8fa2198a3ed5cf5f3835b9):

```
Dim id As String = node.GetAttributeValue("id", "")
```

**Update for updated question**

In addition to the above fix, you are retrieving the HtmlDocument incorrectly. HtmlDocument.Load will either load a file or an HTML string, not retrieve the file from the web server.

You need to modify your code to fetch the data from the URL using HtmlWeb. Replace the following lines:

```
Dim doc As New HtmlDocument() 
doc.LoadHtml("shaggybevo.com/board/register.php")
```

with these:

```
Dim doc As HtmlDocument
Dim web As New HtmlWeb

doc = web.Load("http://shaggybevo.com/board/register.php")
```

Comment: Thanks competent_tech. I fixed that issue but now I am getting a new error on the line where it says "For Each node in Htmlnodes" line. The error is NullReferenceException was unhandled"

Comment: Dim doc As New HtmlDocument()
        doc.LoadHtml("http://www.shaggybevo.com/board/register.php")
        Dim docNode As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode
        Dim nodes As HtmlNodeCollection = docNode.SelectNodes("//input")
        'SelectNodes takes a XPath expression
        For Each node As HtmlNode In nodes
            Dim id As String = node.GetAttributeValue("id", "value")
            ' Fetch id of HTML element
            Dim name As String = node.GetAttributeValue("name", "value")

            Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = id.ToString & name.ToString


        Next

Comment: @ChrisWheelous: Ok, that means that most likely means that the nodes collection is empty, so you should test that prior to using it. Also, I have very little knowledge of xpath, but I am not 100% sure that your query to selectNodes is correct. You might try backing out to a single tag to get it working, then build from there. Here is a link to a tutorial on XPath, just in case: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Comment: @ChrisWheelous: I see what your problem is. I have updated the question with your additional code and modified the answer with the solution.

Comment: Thanks competent_tech..you made my year...well..what's left of it anyways.. :) I've been searching for this answer for about 3 months straight...

Comment: You are very welcome. Remember to click on the checkmark and up arrow next to any answer that solves or helps you solves your question so that future visitors will know this is what helped you.

Comment: One last question for ya...well two...1. I'm a noob and don't see a checkmark or up arrow, and I also want to you give you rep for the answer but I'm not fining those fields...2. with the code above let's say I wanted to get the inner text of a label that proceeds an input how can I grab that with htmlagility pack? I was trying If node.innertext("username") true then ..... but I cannot convert to boolean value.  THanks again.

Comment: @ChrisWheelous: The checkmark should be right under the 0 next to the answer and the up arrow is right above the 0 (I didn't know any of this when I joined up until someone pointed it out). The label text is going to be pretty tricky and I think too long to answer in comments. I recommend that you create a new question, both to help others that have similar problems find it more easily and to help your reputation.